# Copying 2 columns to another spreadsheet

Tags: excel, formula

I have a spreadsheet with the 2 columns with data. If there's data in column A, column B cells are empty, if there's data in column B column A cells are empty. I need to copy both columns into one without any gaps.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9gpK.png)

I am looking for a formula to copy the cells from columns D and E to one in another spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a rather simple formula to use.

assuming your data starts in cells A1 and B1.

In a blank cell (e.g. C1) you can enter the following formula:

```
=IF(A1<>"", A1, IF(B1<>"", B1, ""))
```

Press Enter.
Drag the fill handle down to fill the formula for all the rows where you have data in columns A and B.

Answer (score 0):

Use the top formula and drag to copy down, or use the second formula to fill in dynamically:

```
=Sheet1!D1&Sheet1!E1

or

=Sheet1!D1:D28&Sheet1!E1:E28
```

[image]